# How can echo the previous command I ran to a file?

Tags: bash, unix, zsh

I tried running `echo '$(!!:p)' > /tmp/tmptxt.txt`, however I just get `$(!!:p)`. The previous command may have unescaped characters so I i need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes, so bash won't expand '!!'. Try using double quotes instead, resulting in something like:

```
mjost@tuca:~$ echo hello
hello
mjost@tuca:~$ echo "!!" > file
echo "echo hello" > file
mjost@tuca:~$ cat file 
echo hello
mjost@tuca:~$
```

Anyway, you might want to take a look at a more complete answer with all different possible solutions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run

Good luck!

Comment: What if there's double quotes in the previous command I typed?

Comment: If double quotes you could use: 
   tail -1 $HOME/.bash_history
or better take a look at the link above.

Comment: what about a long command like this? http://pastebin.com/yjypNFP4 tail -1will only give me the last line of the long command. I also might not know how many lines the command takes up